# Identify identical items in two columns?

Tags: r

If I have a dummy data frame as below:

```
  ID Name.x Score.x Name.y Score.y
1  1      A      10      A      20
2  2      A      20      B      30
3  3      B      30      B      40
4  4      C      40      D      50
5  5      D      50      D      60
```

I wonder how to count the number when items in Name.x and in Name.y is identical (e.g. n=3 when A, B, D are identical in the two columns) and the number when items are not identical?

This is just a simplified example. The real data frame is quite large, so it is impossible to count by hand.

Any solution would be appreciated.

Comment: `with(df1,sum(Name.x==Name.y))` and `!=` or use `%in%`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is `intersect/length`

```
v1 <- with(df1, length(intersect(Name.x, Name.y)))
v1
#[1] 3
```

and the ones that are in Name.x and not in 'Name.y'

```
with(df1, length(setdiff(Name.x, Name.y)))
```

and the ones that are in Name.y and not in 'Name.x'

```
with(df1, length(setdiff(Name.y, Name.x)))
```

Or

```
length(unique(unlist(df1[c('Name.x', 'Name.y')]))) - v1
#[1] 1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, Name.x = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "D"), 
    Score.x = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L), Name.y = c("A", "B", 
    "B", "D", "D"), Score.y = c(20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 60L)),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"))
```